# Why doesn't the script to launch Timeline work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I have a problem. I'm relatively new and having trouble working with the Unity Timelines component. I wrote a simple script to launch the timeline, but for some reason it does not work, although a message is output to the console from the method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public class TimelineTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayableDirector timeline;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Timeline is starting");
            timeline.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

What can be done about it? I will be glad for any help!
[image]

The timeline should signal to my own script that starts the dialog. Usually there are no problems with calling the dialog, but for some reason it doesn’t work from the launch of the timeline
[image]

Comment: Can you show us how your PlayableDirector component is set up?

Comment: can you specify what's the  Timeline Track is ? And what you are using the timeline for in general

Comment: @DevAm00 the timeline should signal to my own script that starts the dialog. Usually there are no problems with calling the dialog, but for some reason it doesn’t work from the launch of the timeline (I edit Q and pinned screen)